# My images are not displayed on localhost:8000

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React website code with gatsby and Visual studio code however I don't understand why none of my images are displayed when I view my site on localhost:8000 a question mark in a square is displayed. Can anyone explain this? I'm a beginner at the moment so I can't find anything...

I wonder if it's because I added my image file from my Finder without changing anything in the code but I don't know how to do it

So if anyone would be kind enough to help me that would be great! Thanks

Sorry for my poor French English 
[gatsby][1] [index][2] [button][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXgQ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohQJ.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5XeA.png

Comment: Your images must be URL accessible. If it's outside your public dir (same dir or below your index file), then you will face CORS restriction. Open dev tools and check network tab from where images are loaded

Comment: have you checked your dev-tools? There should be an error in case a resource/image can't be found/displayed as well as the path to the resource itself

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! By actually checking my image is not found but I don't understand I feel like I did everything right.. I add 3 pics to the post if you see something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use images from external sources make sure to include the complete image URL inside of the source of the image.

If you use the HTML `<img>` tag to create a simple image you can see how to do it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp). The problem with the HTML image is this isn't very efficient and costs performance.

Because you are using Gatsby you can use various image plugins that are more optimized compared to the `img` tag. You can use [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) plugin if you want.

Without seeing your code I can't really help you, but I hope this answer helped you find a solution.